# How can you simulate a keypress without the use of external libraries(such as InputSimulator) in a WPF program?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an extension on a WPF program, and I need to simulate a series of keypresses for it. WinForms is unable to be used as a reference. I cannot show code, but none of my code has to do with this anyways. I just need to simulate a keypress at the most basic level so the program thinks the user is typing. Also, the use of external libraries cannot be used because the extension is a single .DLL file added to hundreds of systems, so whole libraries cannot come with it. Thanks - Ethan

Comment: You may wish to look at `ilmerge` as a way around your “no libraries” requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through the use of a technique called [Platform Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) (P/Invoke for short). This lets higher-level code interact with the lower levels of code used by the platform it's running on.

The "higher-level code" in this case is your C# code, the "platform" is the Windows OS and the "lower-level code" are the native libraries that are part of the OS. These native libraries include code to do such things as send keyboard and mouse input, and since these libraries are part of Windows itself, you don't have to package them with your program.

The method you will want to p/invoke is called `SendInput`. It's used to send keyboard and mouse messages to the active program, just as if they were sent by a physical keyboard or mouse. Take a look at this page on [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html) for instructions and an example on how to implement that method. That site is a good general resource for all your p/invoke needs.